# Clickhouse how to merge table with different columns?

Tags: clickhouse

Say I have 2 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_1
(
key1 FixedString(10),
dt Datetime,

data1 Float32 default nan,
data2 Float32 default nan
)
Engine = MergeTree()
order by (key1,dt);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_2
(
key1 FixedString(10),
dt Datetime,

data3 Float32 default nan,
data4 Float32 default nan
)
Engine = MergeTree()
order by (key1,dt);
```

After a while, I realized that it's better to manage data1,data2,data3,data4 in one table, ie. I need a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_3
(
key1 FixedString(10),
dt Datetime,

data1 Float32 default nan,
data2 Float32 default nan,
data3 Float32 default nan,
data4 Float32 default nan
)
Engine = MergeTree()
order by (key1,dt);
```

Since Clickkhouse does not support update...select, I can't find a way to merge table_1 and table_2 into table_3. This can't be done from the python side either, since clickhouse-driver does not support "update".

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two pairs of dates be related via the `key1` field, you could do an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` using a join:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_3 (key1, dt, data1, data2, data3, data4)
SELECT t1.key1, t1.dt, t1.data1, t1.data2, t2.data3, t2.data4
FROM table_1 t1
INNER JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t2.key1 = t1.key1;
```

Note that it is not clear whence is the source of the `dt` value which is desired in the `table_3` output.  Arbitrarily, I am inserting the version from `table_1`.

Comment: This works. However, there're situations where table_1 got many data-fields, while table_2 has only a few data-fields. Would it be possible to "alter table_1 add columns", and then copy data in table_2 into the new columns in table_1?

Comment: No, that sounds like a bad idea, but I can't comment with certainty because I can't even see your data.